# Problem about different bases and digits of a number

Tags: number-theory

Here is the problem:

Let $a_2$, $a_1$, and $a_0$ be three digits. When the 3-digit number $a_2 a_1 a_0$ is read in base $b$ and converted to decimal, the result is 254. When the 3-digit number $a_2 a_1 a_0$ is read in base $b + 1$ and converted to decimal, the result is 330. Finally, when the 3-digit number $a_2 a_1 a_0$ is read in base $b + 2$ and converted to decimal, the result is 416. Find the 3-digit number $a_2 a_1 a_0$. (Express your answer in decimal.)

I tried to solve this problem but then found that as the base gets higher the result of the number gets lower. I don't understand how this problem is possible because of this, but there has to be an answer...

Answer (score 4):

By definition, $n_2n_1n_0$ read in base $m$ is $n_2m^2+n_1m+n_0$. So we have:

$$\begin{equation}
a_2b^2+a_1b+a_0=254\\
a_2(b+1)^2+a_1(b+1)+a_0=330\\
a_2(b+2)^2+a_1(b+2)+a_0=416
\end{equation}$$

Get the differences of the three equations.

$$\begin{equation}
2a_2b+a_2+a_1=76\\
4a_2b+4a_2+2a_1=162\\
2a_2b+3a_2+a_1=86
\end{equation}$$

From the top and bottom ones, $a_2=5$ and now $10b+a_1=71$. $a_1$ is a single digit number so it has to be $a_1=1$ and $b=7$. Substituting this back to the original system of equations yields $a_0=2$.

$$\therefore 512$$